# Can we reduce complexity in comparing each user in array with every another?

Tags: arrays, data-structures, time-complexity

We have an array of users. We want to compare each user with every other user for some reason. Can its complexity be less than n^2 somehow?
Currently the comparison is taking n^2 complexity. I want it to be less than n^2.

Comment: If the arrays are sorted you can use dicotomic search to reduce complexity to log2(N) of finding the first user. Comparing all users once you have the first one will always be N.

Comment: So it ends up being N, isn't it?

Comment: I want to compare every user with another user and not a single user with every other user.

Comment: If you want to compare everyone with everyone I think you can't really do anything about it. Pretty much sounds like the algorithm to traverse a 2D matrix; for each one, you have to compare it to every other one. So it's N(users) compared to N(users) which is N * N

Comment: If you want to compare every user with every other user, your question is basically how to do O(n^2) work in less than O(n^2) time, which is clearly not possible. That said, (a) there may be a way to solve your *actual* problem faster - we can't do much with your question as it stands - and (b) for this and many other problems, you could theoretically split the work over a number of processors to improve the actual running time (albeit not the complexity, assuming a fixed number of processors).

Comment: Whenever somebody asks me a question like this, I respond with, "Are you sure that you must compare each user with every other user?" Most of the time, we can find a way to avoid having to do that. What specific problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

Something like mentioned in comments would work. It is just a problem with finding element in array. I suppose you are picking a user and then you get the for example name of the user, then you have find that user in the array to find other informatioon of that user. You can keep the users sorted by that key values then you can find it in O(logn). Also you can use hashtable which will do the work in constant time.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: In the first place, the question isn't detailed enough to provide a useful answer other than, "Comparing every user against every other requires O(n^2) work, and there is no way to get around it." You might ask for clarification, but that's what comments are for, not answers. Your "answer" makes unsupported assumptions about what the OP really wants to do, and at best provides vague suggestions for a solution to that fictional problem.

Comment: I thought OP's statement in comments "I want to compare every user with another user" was clear enough. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to compare every user to every other user, then complexity is by definition O(n*n).

In practice (as mentioned in the comments), the requirement is unlikely to be "compare every user to every other user", but usually "sort users" or "find most similar user to every given user" or something similar. These task have much lower complexity. However, you need to tell us what the problem is that you are trying to solve.